# Whats the regexp to detect a string with at least 6 characters and without whitespace?

Tags: regex

I'm still learning regexp and I was wondering what the regexp would look like for detecting a string with at least 6 characters and without any whitespace?

I'm using javascript, so why doesn't this work?

```
if (VAL.match( /^\S{6,}$/) ) return true;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can match a whitespace character with a `\s`, and a non-whitespace character with `\S`. So this should work for you:

```
/^\S{6,}$/
```

However you didn't specify the flavor of regex you're using. You may need to escape the bracket or use another character class if `\S` is not available.

EDIT (Lars): The question was "at least 6 characters" - modified to {6,}

Comment: The question was "at least 6 characters", which would be `/^\S{6,}$/
`

Comment: I'm using javascript...here is my code: `if (VAL.match( /^\S{6,}$/) ) return true;` it doesn't return true though, even if the input is correct...

Comment: @yourfriendzak: it should work. Works here. What's the content of `VAL`?

Comment: @sidyll VAL == jQuery.val() I believe

Comment: Open your console and type `VAL` to the what's returned. Also, while you're there, try `"string".match(/^\S{6,}$/)`

Comment: @sidyll what's returned is "ReferenceError" which is odd because its working fine in all my other functions. "string".match(/^\S{6,}$/) works correctly in the console...it returns the string when true and null when false

Comment: Could be a problem with converting this exp to valid javascript? for example, I needed to add a parenthesis at the end in order not to get an error: /^\S{6,}$/)

Comment: how is the original different from the solutions? did the original got edited to the correct one? this is misleading...

Answer (score 4):

Try the following regex:

```
/^\S{6,}$/
```